# how connection odoo.conf with postgresql by pycharm in odoo 15

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo, odoo-15

i want configration odoo.conf with postgresql pgadmin by pycharm
But I have a problem

odoo.conf.py

[image]

edit configrations

[image]

problem message:

```
/home/ayobqorban/odoo/testodoo/odoo15/venv/bin/python /home/ayobqorban/odoo/testodoo/odoo15/odoo-bin --config=/home/ayobqorban/odoo/testodoo/odoo15/debian/odoo.conf 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayobqorban/odoo/testodoo/odoo15/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/home/ayobqorban/odoo/testodoo/odoo15/odoo/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    import PyPDF2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: you need the install [these](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/requirements.txt) libraries in your python environment,**how to** after activating your environment(it's usually enabled in the Terminal in PyCharm), run this command `pip install -r https://github.com/odoo/odoo/raw/15.0/requirements.txt`

Comment: you can watch https://youtu.be/p7SJW36lqVE?t=458 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8C097f6Hcg